# Poner funcion de respuesta de ajax en un FOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buen dia, perdonen alguno de uds sabra como acceder a la data de la respuesta que traigo de ajax, lo siguiente me funciona:

```
 $.each(data.data, function  (i, item) { })
```

Pero tengo un for, donde hago un recorrido para un pagineo, pero si coloco el each dentro del for, me duplica toda la data...

```
for (var i = start_index; i <= end_index; i++) {}
```

Sera posible hacer lo siguiente? Para poder acceder en un mismo for tanto mi funcion, como acceder a la data? para que no me duplique la informacion que traigo como respuesta?

```
for (var i = start_index; i <= end_index; i++ , data.data, function  (i, item)) {}
```

Comment: Claramente no es posible, supongo que lo has intentado. La estructura de un [bucle `for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) en Javascript tiene una definición muy precisa: `for ([expresion-inicial]; [condicion]; [expresion-final])sentencia`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras soy principiante amigo pido disculpas jej,  de hecho lo estuve intentando jejeje habra alguna manera de poder tener ambas cosas? es que si me deja poner uno dentro del otro pero me duplica la informacion

Comment: Podrías aclarar más tu pregunta añadiendo un [mre]. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. No sabemos qué es `data.data`, suponemos que algún tipo de Array, y tampoco sabemos lo que quieres mostrar del mismo, ni cómo quieres mostrarlo. Hablas de paginado, pero el paginado te lo debería dar tu petición, ¿o acaso lo estás paginando del lado cliente? Saludos

Comment: entiendo, permitime

Comment: creo que es mejor poner tu código completo de este for y `$.each` porque no se logra entender tu escenario de la forma en la que lo estás explicando, según entiendo tienes un bucle for que ejecuta ajax request paginadas (url?page=1,url?page=2,etc.) luego la respuesta que es al  parecer un arreglo la recorres con `$.each` y dices que esto te "duplica la data", quizás el problema sea en el cómo estas guardando la data de cada consulta paginada que haces, es decir, lo que esta dentro del `$.each`. Pero bueno sin el código poco se puede hacer